# Flot chart day binding issue

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a custom date filter on my page. User can select maximum two months data means only sixty days. Now upon filtering I got my data for 60 days,but when passing it to the flot chart it will only display 30 days on the chart. Can anybody help me in this. Here is my code:

```
(function () {
    var plot = $.plot('#flotBars', flotBarsData, {
        colors: ['#8CC9E8'],
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.8,
                align: 'center'
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: 'categories',
            tickLength: 0
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            labelMargin: 15,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: '%y',
            shifts: {
                x: -10,
                y: 20
            },
            defaultTheme: false
        },
        yaxis: {
            minTickSize: 0,
            tickDecimals: 0,
            min: 0,
            axisLabelPadding: 3,
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                return v;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            noColumns: 0,
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
            position: "nw"
        }
    });
})();
```

Here is the screenshot of my chart and filter selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the screenshot, you have only 31 categories on the x-axis, presumely one for each day. On some days there are two bars behind each other, one for each month.

If you want to continue to use **categories** mode, you have to give the data unique x axis values (running numbers from 1 to 61 for example). Or you use **time** mode and show the real dates on the x-axis (see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) and [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/index.html) for **time** mode).

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is there any other way that we can display data for these 61 days?

Comment: Yes, see the second part of my answer.

Comment: I think when we show real dates then it will not look good and even not readable.

Comment: For that you could limit the numbers of labels on the axis to something like every 5th day or format the dates as (day, linebreak, month-number) if you need a label for every day.

Comment: Nothing of my own, but the links in the answer should cover it.